# Dining Philosophers errors

Tags: c

I am having a little headache to run my algorithm on Ubuntu. It seems to be working just fine on Windows (Dev C++ or CodeBlocks), but when I try to run it on Geany I keep getting error:

```
Filosofos.cpp:144:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

And it highlights this area as error:

```
iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *)philosopher, (int*)p[1]);
```

As my research, I tried to change to `long int`, `long long` — but without success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define N 5  /* amount of philosophers*/
#define LEFT (i+N-1)%N/* left neighbor i */
#define RIGHT (i+1)%N   /* right neighbor i */
#define THINKING 0 /*  philosopher thinking */
#define HUNGRY 1 /* philosopher tries to catch the fork */
#define EATING 2 /* philosopher eating */
#define TRUE 1

sem_t s[N];                 //one semaphore for each philosopher
sem_t mutex;
int   state[N];
//array to control philosophers state
pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4, thread5;
//one thread for each philosopher
void take_forks(int i);
void put_forks(int i);
void test(int i);
void think(int i);
void eat(int i);

/* i: number of the philosopher, from 0 to N-1 */
void philosopher(int i) {
    while (TRUE) {
        think(i);  /
        take_forks(i); /* take two forks or block it */
        eat(i);
        put_forks(i);
    }
}

void take_forks(int i) {
    sem_wait(&mutex); //down(&mutex); /* entra na regiao cri­tica */
    state[i] = HUNGRY; /* change the state to hungry */
    printf("philosopher %d HUNGRY\n",i);
    test(i);  /* try to catch two forks */
    sem_post (&mutex); // up(&mutex);  /* get out the critical region*/
    sem_wait(&s[i]); // down(&s[i]); /* block if the forks are not available */
}

void put_forks(int i) {
    sem_wait(&mutex); // down(&mutex); /* get in the critical region */
    state[i] = THINKING; /* Philosopher has ended eating  */
    printf("philosopher %d THINKING\n",i);
    test(LEFT);  /* check if the left neighbor can eat now */
    test(RIGHT); /* check if the right neighbor can eat now */
    sem_post(&mutex); // up(&mutex);  /* get out of the critical region*/
}

void test(int i) {  //test if the philosopher´s neighbors can eat
    if (state[i] == HUNGRY && state[LEFT] != EATING && state[RIGHT] != EATING) {
        state[i] = EATING;
        printf("philosopher %d EATING\n",i);
        sem_post(&s[i]); //up(&s[i]);
    }
}

void think(int i) {
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    return;
}

void eat(int i) {
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    return;
}

////////////// MAIN FUNCTION////////////////////////
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int iret1, iret2, iret3, iret4, iret5;
    int i;
    int p[N] ;

    int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);

    for (i= 0; i < N ;i++ ) {
        sem_init(&s[i], 0, 1);
        p[i] = i;
    }
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *) philosopher, (int *) p[1]);
    iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *) philosopher, (int *) p[2]);
    iret3 = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, (void *) philosopher, (int *) p[3]);
    iret4 = pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, (void *) philosopher, (int *) p[4]);
    iret5 = pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, (void *) philosopher, (int *) p[0]);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread4, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread5, NULL);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that when you start creating variables by appending numbers, then you are probably doing something wrong. This almost always indicates that you need to use an array and/or for loop instead.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the thread start function should be

```
void *(*)(void *);
```

so, `philosopher()`, needs to be changed to

```
void *philosopher(void *data)
{
    int i = *(int *) data;
    // The rest of the function
}
```

and then in `main()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, philosopher, &p[i]);
}
```

The `for` loop is here so that I avoid repeating the same code, stick to the DRY principle because if you don't, then maintaining your code will become impossible.

This is your code, but fixed and improved, specially readability. I wish more programmers value readability, because reading code is what we do most, we read a lot more than we write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 5                  /* amount of philosophers              */
#define LEFT (i + N - 1) % N /* left neighbor i                     */
#define RIGHT (i + 1) % N    /* right neighbor i                    */
#define THINKING 0           /*  philosopher thinking               */
#define HUNGRY 1             /* philosopher tries to catch the fork */
#define EATING 2             /* philosopher eating                  */
#define TRUE 1

sem_t s[N];                 // one semaphore for each philosopher
sem_t mutex;
int state[N];

void take_forks(int i);
void put_forks(int i);
void test(int i);
void think(int i);
void eat(int i);

void *
philosopher(void *data) 
{
    int i = *(int *) data;
    while (TRUE) {
        think(i);
        take_forks(i); /* take two forks or block it */
        eat(i);
        put_forks(i);
    }
}

void
take_forks(int i) 
{
    sem_wait(&mutex);

    state[i] = HUNGRY;
    printf("philosopher %d HUNGRY\n", i);

    test(i);  /* try to catch two forks */

    sem_post (&mutex);
    sem_wait(&s[i]);
}

void 
put_forks(int i)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex);

    state[i] = THINKING;
    printf("philosopher %d THINKING\n", i);

    test(LEFT);  /* check if the left neighbor can eat now */
    test(RIGHT); /* check if the right neighbor can eat now */

    sem_post(&mutex);
}

void 
test(int i)
{
    if ((state[i] == HUNGRY) && (state[LEFT] != EATING) && (state[RIGHT] != EATING)) {
        state[i] = EATING;
        printf("philosopher %d EATING\n", i);
        sem_post(&s[i]);
    }
}

void 
think(int i) 
{
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    return;
}

void 
eat(int i) 
{
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    pthread_t thread[N];
    int p[N];

    int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);

    for (i= 0; i < N ;i++ ) {
        sem_init(&s[i], 0, 1);
        p[i] = i;
    }
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, philosopher, &p[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Don't use comments, to say something that is very clear like

```
state = NEW_STATE; // Change the state to NEW_STATE
```